# jQuery replace href URL on PHP page

Tags: jquery, replace, href, attr

I am trying to achieve something that should be easy in theory

I have a php (zen-cart) generated page

I want to change 1 URL to another one, using jQuery.

So I would load the jQuery in the head section, then at the bottom of my document I would stick:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("a[href='http://myurl']").attr('href', 'http://anotherURL')
    });
 </script>
```

Yet, this is not working... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does `alert($("a[href='http://myurl']").length)` say?

Comment: Just an FYI, there's no need to stick this at the bottom of the page either. Code executed in `$(document).ready` ensures that the entire DOM is loaded first.

Comment: @Alex If it is `undefined` then I'd assume you didn't load jQuery properly.

Comment: @Alex What does `alert(typeof jQuery)` say?

Comment: if jquery wasn't loaded, there wouldn't have been an alert of 'undefined' the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[href*='http://myurl']").attr('href', 'http://anotherURL');
});`

Comment: Yeah this should be the right thing, still it's not working on my page... must be zencart issue then? I dunno... I am helping a friend with this site... http://www.derbycitycomputers.com/ problem with zencart is the home link is broken, and issue is the & sign in the home link... so since I dunno ho to fix it in php and zencart files, I was trying to solve it the rough way using jquery... still, it's not working O___o

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("a[href*='http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php&amp;zenid=f094247dde79bd56a47207b474ab3f29']").attr('href', 'http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php?zenid=f094247dde79bd56a47207b474ab3f29')
 });
</script>

Comment: Your script is looking for a encoded url, is the url encoded in the actual html? does it say `&zenid=` or `&amp;zenid=`?

Comment: Well I tried both of them and neither seem to work. Anyway according to the source its &amp;

Comment: There is no `a` with an HREF equal to `http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php&amp;zenid=f094247dde79bd56a47207b474ab3f29` on the homepage.

Comment: I think I'll try a bit more then I will give up on this one if it doesnt work! Thx a lot for pointing me in this direction Jamie!

Comment: which link are you trying to change exactly?

Comment: I have to change the HOME in the navbar. Since it changes on every reload,I need to change an URL like this: http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php&amp; into a url like this http://derbycitycomputers.com

Comment: I tried the above with no luck... dunno what to say :) THX everyone!

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { 

    $("a[href*='http://derbycitycomputers.com/index.php&']").attr('href', 'http://derbycitycomputers.com/'); 
}); `